# Python update - how to update `py` to point to new version?

Tags: python, upgrade, python-venv, python-py

I started learning Python on v3.7, and now v3.8 is out.

I've downloaded 3.8.0 and installed it to a new `python38` directory alongside my `python37` folder. The path was updated and now includes both python v3.7 and v3.8.

#### How to update `py`?

If I open up a new **Command Window** or **Git Bash** window, `python --version` is updated, but not `py --version`, how do I update `py` to point to the latest version?

Are there any other considerations with respect to virtual environments?

They should remain pointing to the version of python they were built with - is that true of both `python` and `py` when a venv is active?

---

**Note:** `py` is a command-line python launcher tool included with Python for Windows as of v3.3

Comment: what is `py`? is that an alias?

Comment: py is a command included as of Python3 that allows you to call the "default" python install. But I'm having a really hard time finding any documentation on it. In another Q&A it mentioned it points to the default, but no link to docs or mention of how to update the default install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a while, I stumbled into the answer for the `py` update part, at least.

The `py` command is an executable included with **Windows** Python distributions starting with Python v3.3. It is called the ["Python Launcher for Windows" in the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows).

- ***Note:** An official `py` command is not included with Linux Python distributions, though there is the [Py Launcher for Unix](https://python-launcher.app/) available for Linux that can be installed separately and works like the Windows version.*

The documentation on the Python Launcher is pretty complete, but to answer my original question, I had set the environment variable `PY_PYTHON` to `3.7` to declare the default Python version for `py` to use.

I was able to fix the issue by updating this to `3.8` and restarting any terminal and program that uses a terminal to access py/python. There are other Python environment variables so I updated them all:

**UPDATE:** I was able to completely remove the `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` variables and just use `PY_PYTHON` to control the default version. You can read more about these variables [in the Environment Variables section of the Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#environment-variables)

- set `PY_PYTHON` to `3.8`
- set `PYTHONHOME` to my new Python38 directory
- for `PYTHONPATH` added the new `python38` and `python38/scripts` directories.

***Note:** After updating environment variables, you will need to restart some programs, and others might require either a logout or full reboot (was true of VS Code on Windows).*

---

#### More info on `py` command and versions

You can get a list of basic `py` commands using `py --help`:

```bash
$ py --help
Python Launcher for Windows Version 3.8.150.1013

usage:
C:\WINDOWS\py.exe [launcher-args] [python-args] script [script-args]

Launcher arguments:

-2     : Launch the latest Python 2.x version
-3     : Launch the latest Python 3.x version
-X.Y   : Launch the specified Python version
     The above all default to 64 bit if a matching 64 bit python is present.
-X.Y-32: Launch the specified 32bit Python version
-X-32  : Launch the latest 32bit Python X version
-X.Y-64: Launch the specified 64bit Python version
-X-64  : Launch the latest 64bit Python X version
-0  --list       : List the available pythons
-0p --list-paths : List with paths
```

The version strings above used to launch a particular version of python are what can be put into the `PY_PYTHON` environment variable. For example, if you just wanted the latest Python3, then use `3`, for a particular Python3, use `3.8`, or for the 32-bit version, use `3.8-32`, etc.